# How do I find out which version of Exchange my Outlook client is connecting to?

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

Are there any tell-tale signs?

Comment: See also [*Determine the version of Microsoft Exchange Server my account connects to*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/determine-the-version-of-microsoft-exchange-server-my-account-connects-to-d427465a-ce3b-42bd-9d83-c7d893d5d334).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold the CTRL key, then right click the Outlook tray icon, then select Connection status from the context menu, then look for the version number in the far right column for the mail component. This is the build number of the Exchange server Outlook is connected to. Find your version based on the build numbers [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098(EXCHG.141).aspx)